# How can I make text aligned to the middle of the icon that resides beside the text?

Tags: html, image, web, alignment

HTML Snippet:

```
<tr>
<td><img src="images/globeLogo.png" vspace="-5"/>G.M. Applied Technologies Canada<br />
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr>
<td><img src="images/globeLogo.png" vspace="-5" /><span style="position:relative; top:-10px; left:10px;">G.M. Applied Technologies Canada</span><br />
</tr>
```

Comment: you may change the top and left values according to your requirements